# How do I make coordinates relate to global values?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender, and I'm already tired of the coordinate system in the small menu at the bottom left going to 0,0,0 on translate every time I go to edit a new/different vertex. How could I make the coordinates appear as global values all of the time?

E.g. I want the vertex at coordinate 1,2,0 to appear as 1,2,0 in the transform menu at the bottom left of the screen, and if I come back to edit that vertex later, still be seen as 1,2,0 instead of resetting the coordinates to 0,0,0 as it does by default.

Note, I use the exact decimal value menu at the bottom left. I do not want to have hand drawn, or approximate meshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "transform menu at the bottom left".

When I translate a vertex of a mesh object while in Edit Mode, the Translate Operator is invoked and its properties are editable in the lower portion of the tool panel. Because the translation moves a vertex, the translation vector displayed here is the delta (the difference between the original position and the new position; the amount the vertex was moved.)

However in the upper right is the Transform Panel which displays the location of the current vertex, and this panel can be set to display either the Global or Local coordinates of the selected vertex, which sounds like what you want.

Does that help at all?

[image]

Comment: Yes that helps quite a lot, in that I now know that I need to find out how to bring up the transform panel in the top right because it is not enabled by default. For the record, I was talking about the translate operator because that is the only thing that I could see that would allow direct manipulation of vertices.

Comment: That side panel is the Properties Region and can be shown/hidden with the 'n' key.